# Power Automate Flow - Trigger Condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have a list with a lot of flows doing certain things at different points.  One flow I'm working on is to send an email notification when an item's Status equals Approved.  The flow I have right now has conditions when an item is modified, but once the conditions are met, it fires off like 20 emails.

So I need to add a trigger condition.  What I'm after is to trigger the flow when the Choice column - PMO *Final* Approval = Approved.  I don't know how to set up the syntax for trigger conditions.  Could someone please help me write this out?

It's probably fairly basic, but I just don't know it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use trigger condition in below format:

```
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/PMOFinalApproval/Value'], 'Approved')
```

**OR**:

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['PMOFinalApproval']?['Value'], 'Approved')
```

Use correct **internal name** of your SharePoint choice column, check [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)